# Is there an error in this code?

Tags: c

A question ask me if this code, contains any error.
The compiler doesn't give me any errors but this code contains some arguments that I don't know

The code is this:

```
int* mycalloc(int n) {
   int *p = malloc(n*sizeof(int)), *q; //what does the ", *q"?
   for (q=p; q<=p+n; ++q) *q = 0; 
   return p;
}
```

The possible solutions are:

1. The program is correct
2. There is an error at line 1
3. There is an error at line 2
4. There is an error at line 3
5. There is an error at line 4

Comment: `, *q` is the syntax of declaration for multiple variables. error is at line 3, should be `q < p + n`

Comment: What happens if you pass `0` to `mycalloc`. How many elments are allocated? How many are initialized?

Comment: Error at line 3, but the question is: do you understand what `for (q=p; q<=p+n; ++q)` is doing?

Comment: No I don't understand.. I'm trying to understand but I don't

Comment: @marco I wrote an answer explaining what it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `compile time` error in the above code but at **run time** it will crash because of `q<=p+n`. `q` is simply an integer pointer.
It should be

```
for (q=p; q<p+n; ++q) /** it works even though n is zero or you can add seperate if condition for the same, this may be the interviewer concern **/
    *q = 0;
```

Comment: It isn’t guaranteed to crash, but writing beyond the boundaries of the allocated array gives undefined behaviour, and one possible result is a crash

Answer (score 0):

What `mymalloc` is doing is allocating space for `n` integers and initialize
them with 0.

This could have been done so:

```
int *mymalloc(size_t n)
{
    int *arr = malloc(n * sizeof *arr);
    if(arr == NULL)
        return NULL;

    memset(arr, 0, n * sizeof *arr);
    return arr;
}
```

or better

```
int *mymalloc(size_t n)
{
    return calloc(n, sizeof int);
}
```

The way your function is doing this, is by looping through the array using a
pointer `q`. Let me explain

```
int *p = malloc(n*sizeof(int)), *q;
```

It declares two `int*` (pointers to `int`) variables `p` and `q`. `p` is
initialized with the values returned by `malloc` and `q` is left uninitialized.
It's the same as doing:

```
int *p;
int *q;

p = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
```

but in one line.

The next part is the interesting one:

```
for (q=p; q<p+n; ++q)
    *q = 0;
```

First I corrected the condition and wrote it in two lines.

You can read this loop as follows:

- initialize `q` with the same value as `p`, i.e. `p` and `q` point to the start
  of the allocated memory
- end the loop when `q` is pointing **beyond** the allocated memory
- at the end of the loop, do `++q`, which makes `q` go to the next `int`
- In the loop do `*q = 0`, equivalent to `q[0] = 0`, thus setting the integer to
  0 that is pointed to by `q`.

Let us think about the memory layout. Let's say `n = 5`. In my graphic `?`
represents an unkown value.

```
BEFORE THE LOOP
b = the start of the allocated memory aka malloc return value
si = size of an integer in bytes, mostly 4

                                                       (beyond the limits)
     b+0      b+1*si     b+2*si   b+3*si     b+4*si    b+5*si
     +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
     | ????    | ????    | ????    | ????    | ????    |
     +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
     ^
     |
     p
```

In the first loop, `q` is set to `p` and `*q = 0` is executed. It's the same as
doing `p[0] = 0`.

```
FIRST ITERATION
b = the start of the allocated memory aka malloc return value
si = size of an integer in bytes, mostly 4

                                                       (beyond the limits)
     b+0      b+1*si     b+2*si   b+3*si     b+4*si    b+5*si
     +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
     | 0       | ????    | ????    | ????    | ????    |
     +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
     ^
     |
     p,q
```

This is how the memory would look like after `*q=0`. Then the next loop is
executed, but before of that `q++` is executed

```
BEFORE SECOND ITERATION, `q++`
b = the start of the allocated memory aka malloc return value
si = size of an integer in bytes, mostly 4

                                                       (beyond the limits)
     b+0      b+1*si     b+2*si   b+3*si     b+4*si    b+5*si
     +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
     | 0       | ????    | ????    | ????    | ????    |
     +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
     ^         ^
     |         |
     p         q
```

Now `*q = 0` is executed, which is the same as `p[1] = 0`:

```
SECOND ITERATION,
b = the start of the allocated memory aka malloc return value
si = size of an integer in bytes, mostly 4

                                                       (beyond the limits)
     b+0      b+1*si     b+2*si   b+3*si     b+4*si    b+5*si
     +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
     | 0       | 0       | ????    | ????    | ????    |
     +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
     ^         ^
     |         |
     p         q
```

Then the loop continues, and you get now the point. This is why in your code the
condition of the loop `q <= p+n` is wrong, because it would do 1 step farther
than it needs and would write a 0 beyond the limits.

You loop is using pointer arithmetic. Pointer arithmetic is similar to regular
arithmetic (i.e. addition, subtraction with natural numbers), **but** it takes
the size of the object in consideration.

Consider this code

```
int p[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int *q = p;
```

`p` is an array of `int` of dimension 5. The common size of `int` is 4, that
means that the array `q` needs 20 bytes of memory. The first 4 bytes are for
`p[0]`, the next 4 for `p[1]`, etc. `q` is a pointer to `int` pointing at the
first element of the array `p`. In fact this code is equivalent to

```
int p[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int *q = &(p[0]);
```

That is what people call array decay, meaning that you can access the array as
if where a pointer. For pointer arithmetic there is almost no distinction
between the two.

What is pointer arithmetic then?

This: `p+2`. This will get you a pointer that is 2 spaces after `p`. Note that
I'm using the word space and not byte, and that's because depending on the type
of `p`, the number of bytes will be different. Mathematically what the compiler
is doing is calculating the address from

> *address where p is pointing + 2x(number of bytes for an int)*
>
> because the compiler knows the type of the pointer.

That's why you can also have expressions like `p++` when `p` is a pointer. It is
doing `p = p + 1` which is `p = &(p[1]);`.

```
b is the base address where the memory starts

memory
address      b+0      b+1*si     b+2*si   b+3*si     b+4*si    
             +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
             | 1       | 2       | 3       | 4       | 5       |
             +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
             p         p+1       p+2       p+3       p+4

pointer
(pointer arithmetic)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from tools import *
#from ml import *
import argparse
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from sklearn import svm
import numpy as np
import os
import cv2



parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--mode', '-mode', help="Mode : train or predict", type=str)
parser.add_argument('--a', '-algorithm', help="algorithm/model name", type=str)
parser.add_argument('--i', '-image', help="licence plate to read", type=str)
parser.add_argument('--model', '-model', help="Model file path", type=str)
#parser.add_argument('--d', '-dataset', help="dataset folder path", type=str)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.